# Using a specific network interface for a socket in windows

Tags: windows, networking, binding, sockets, bind

Is there a reliable way in Windows, apart from changing the routing table, to force a newly created socket to use a specific network interface? I understand that `bind()` to the interface's IP address does not guarantee this.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

(Ok second time lucky..)

FYI there's another question here [perform connect() on specific network adapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1237679/perform-connect-on-specific-network-adapter) along the same lines...

According to [The Cable Guy](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2007.09.cableguy.aspx)

> Windows XP and Windows Server® 2003
> use the weak host model for sends and
> receives for all IPv4 interfaces and
> the strong host model for sends and
> receives for all IPv6 interfaces. You
> cannot configure this behavior. The
> Next Generation TCP/IP stack in
> Windows Vista and Windows Server 2008
> supports strong host sends and
> receives for both IPv4 and IPv6 by
> default on all interfaces except the
> Teredo tunneling interface for a
> Teredo host-specific relay.

So to answer your question (properly, this time) in Windows XP and Windows Server 2003 IP4 no, but for IP6 yes. And for Windows Vista and Windows 2008 yes (except for certain circumstances).

Also from https://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?487139-Socket-binding-with-routing-table

> On Windows, a call to bind() affects
> card selection only incoming traffic,
> not outgoing traffic. Thus, on a
> client running in a multi-homed system
> (i.e., more than one interface card),
> it's the network stack that selects
> the card to use, and it makes its
> selection based solely on the
> destination IP, which in turn is based
> on the routing table. A call to bind()
> will not affect the choice of the card
> in any way.
>
> It's got something to do with
> something called a "Weak End System"
> ("Weak E/S") model. **Vista changed to a
> strong E/S model, so the issue might
> not arise under Vista**. But all prior
> versions of Windows used the weak E/S
> model.
>
> With a weak E/S model, it's the
> routing table that decides which card
> is used for outgoing traffic in a
> multihomed system.
>
> See if these threads offer some
> insight:
>
> "Local socket binding on multihomed
> host in Windows XP does not work" at
> http://www.codeguru.com/forum/showthread.php?t=452337
>
> "How to connect a port to a specified
> Networkcard?" at
> http://www.codeguru.com/forum/showthread.php?t=451117.
> This thread mentions the
> CreateIpForwardEntry() function, which
> (I think) can be used to create an
> entry in the routing table so that all
> outgoing IP traffic with a specified
> server is routed via a specified
> adapter.
>
> "Working with 2 Ethernet cards" at
> http://www.codeguru.com/forum/showthread.php?t=448863
>
> "Strange bind behavior on multihomed
> system" at
> http://www.codeguru.com/forum/showthread.php?t=452368

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks,
Unless I am missing something, neither answer is relevant, as SO_BINDTODEVICE is not relevant to windows.

I suspect your summary is correct though, even though I do not have the evidence.

Comment: Oops right you are! Updated my answer above with better info - sorry!

Comment: Note that the weak and strong host models do not affect how traffic sent from a socket is routed. I.e. the strong host model ensures that traffic leaving a network adapter uses that adapter's assigned IP address, but does not affect how the network stack in the host itself selects the outgoing adapter to actually use. This is actually explained in "The Cable Guy" link above, as well as on Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Host_model

Comment: In certain protocols, such as with icmpv6 neighbor discovery, it is possible to send packets with the unspecified address (i.e. `::`) as the source. A router solicitation message for instance might have (dst `ff02::2` (link local all routers), and `::` as source). If one opened a raw IPv6 socket on windows and sent such a packet, would it go out on all interfaces? Is the implication in this case that there is no other way to restrict the output interface besides forcing the src to be the interface's link-local IP?

Comment: So, 11 years later, the best answer is still "Not possible"?

Comment: All of the CodeGuru links in this answer are broken

Comment: (Main (first) CodeGuru link fixed)

Comment: Look at the other answer, 10 years later it actually seems possible.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you say bind is not working reliably. Granted I have not done exhaustive testing, but the following solution worked for me (Win10, Visual Studio 2019). I needed to send a broadcast message via a particular NIC, where multiple NICs might be present on a computer. In the snippet below, I want the broadcast message to go out on the NIC with IP of .202.106.

In summary:

- create a socket
- create a sockaddr_in address with the IP address of the NIC you want to send FROM
- bind the socket to that FROM sockaddr_in
- create another sockaddr_in with the IP of your broadcast address (255.255.255.255)
- do a sendto, passing the socket created is step 1, and the sockaddr of the broadcast address.

`

```
static WSADATA     wsaData;

static int ServoSendPort = 8888;
static char ServoSendNetwork[] = "192.168.202.106";
static char ServoSendBroadcast[] = "192.168.255.255";
```

`
... < snip >

```
if ( WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsaData) != NO_ERROR )
      return false;


// Make a UDP socket
SOCKET ServoSendSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);
int iOptVal = TRUE;
int iOptLen = sizeof(int);
int RetVal = setsockopt(ServoSendSocket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BROADCAST, (char*)&iOptVal, iOptLen);
              
// Bind it to a particular interface
sockaddr_in ServoBindAddr={0};
ServoBindAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
ServoBindAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr( ServoSendNetwork ); // target NIC
ServoBindAddr.sin_port = htons( ServoSendPort );
int bindRetVal = bind( ServoSendSocket, (sockaddr*) &ServoBindAddr, sizeof(ServoBindAddr) );
if (bindRetVal == SOCKET_ERROR )
{
    int ErrorCode = WSAGetLastError();
    CString errMsg;
    errMsg.Format (  _T("rats!  bind() didn't work!  Error code %d\n"), ErrorCode );
    OutputDebugString( errMsg );
}


// now create the address to send to...
sockaddr_in ServoSendAddr={0};
ServoSendAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
ServoSendAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr( ServoSendBroadcast ); // 
ServoSendAddr.sin_port = htons( ServoSendPort );
```

...

```
#define NUM_BYTES_SERVO_SEND 20
unsigned char sendBuf[NUM_BYTES_SERVO_SEND];
int BufLen = NUM_BYTES_SERVO_SEND;

ServoSocketStatus = sendto(ServoSendSocket, (char*)sendBuf, BufLen, 0, (SOCKADDR *) &ServoSendAddr, sizeof(ServoSendAddr));
if(ServoSocketStatus == SOCKET_ERROR)
{
    ServoUdpSendBytes = WSAGetLastError();
    CString message;
    message.Format(_T("Error transmitting UDP message to Servo Controller: %d."), ServoSocketStatus);
    OutputDebugString(message);
    return false;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks. I've asked this during 2010, at which time bind() definitely wasn't doing so reliably, glad to hear that's resolved now :)

Comment: Was looking for such a refresh of the answer. I wonder how things are supposed to be handled on stackoverflow for that.