# How to get *my* ip from udp endpoint

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

Boost.Asio's `udp::endpoint` has a member that is remote address. Because I'm listening on multiple interfaces (like this):

```
udp_socket(io_service, udp::endpoint(udp::v4(), port))
```

In my handler, I do not know which network interface received the packet.

Without iterating over network interfaces and looking for a similarity between the endpoint address and my IP on each interface, can I get my IP for the interface that I got message from?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No.  Boost.Asio does not expose the ability to identify the datagram's destination address.

The [`socket::aync_receive_from()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_datagram_socket/async_receive_from/overload1.html) and [`socket::receive_from()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_datagram_socket/receive_from/overload1.html) operations perform the native socket operations within [`boost::asio::detail::socket_ops::recvfrom()`](https://github.com/boostorg/asio/blob/boost-1.55.0/include/boost/asio/detail/impl/socket_ops.ipp#L870).  On Windows, [`WSARecvFrom()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms741686(v=vs.85).aspx) provides no way to extract lower layer information from the protocol stack.  On Linux, the [`IP_PKTINFO`](http://linux.die.net/man/7/ip) socket option can provided to datagram oriented sockets enabling [`recvfrom()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/recv) to populate the `msghdr.msg_control` buffer with ancillary information, such as the interface index on which the packet was received and the destination address in the packet header.  However, the Boost.Asio [implementation](https://github.com/boostorg/asio/blob/4f11be2/include/boost/asio/detail/impl/socket_ops.ipp#L910-L915) does not use the`msg_control` field:

```cpp
msghdr msg = msghdr();
init_msghdr_msg_name(msg.msg_name, addr);
msg.msg_namelen = static_cast<int>(*addrlen);
msg.msg_iov = bufs;
msg.msg_iovlen = static_cast<int>(count);
signed_size_type result = error_wrapper(::recvmsg(s, &msg, flags), ec);
```

As suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14807025) answer, one can:

- Use lower-level system calls. (i.e. `IP_PKTINFO` and `recvfrom()`)
- Explicitly bind a socket to each interface rather than `INADDR_ANY`, causing the [`socket::local_endpoint()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_datagram_socket/local_endpoint/overload1.html) to return a specific interface.  The completion handlers will need some way to obtain the local endpoint on the socket for which the operation was invoked, such as passing a reference to the socket or its local endpoint via `boost::bind()`.

Comment: but funny thing is when I take endpoint, change its port(it uses diff port for listening) and send reply sender gets a reply... does that mean boost replies on all interfaces ?                              i send like this in handler: request_source.port(reply_port);
                    boost::asio::ip::udp::socket udp_socket(service, boost::asio::ip::udp::endpoint( boost::asio::ip::address(), 0));
                    udp_socket.send_to(boost::asio::buffer(reply,reply.size()), request_source);

Comment: No, routing occurs at the kernel level.  The kernel functions as a router, using the destination address of the outbound data to determine the best possible route for the data, such as which interface will actually write the data.  Hence, it is possible to send data to a socket that has bound to the IP on `eth0`, but the kernel determines the best route to the data's destination is actually through `eth1`, so the data is sent from `eth1` with a source address of `eth0`.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understand you have different [boost::asio::ip::udp::sockets](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ip__udp/socket.html). And in case one of them recieves a message you want to know the local ip address of that socket/the interface that socket uses.

So if `socket` is the socket that recives the msg you should be able to get the ip in the handler by

```
socket.local_endpoint().address()
```

See [local_endpoint()](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_datagram_socket/local_endpoint.html) and [address()](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ip__basic_endpoint/address/overload1.html) in the boost manual.

Comment: nah i have 1 socket, it just listens on any address... like this: udp_socket(io_service, udp::endpoint(udp::v4(), port))  /*...*/                                        start_receive()
{
    udp_socket.async_receive_from(
        boost::asio::buffer(m_recv_buffer), remote_endpoint, ...

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl Ah, ok. But the call to `local_endpoint()` in the handler should work nevertheless, shouldn't it?

Comment: nah i just get 0.0.0.0

Comment: Ok, strange. I'll check it on my machine later.

Comment: make sure to construct socket like this: udp_socket(io_service, udp::endpoint(udp::v4(), port))

Answer (score 2):

i think you should explicit specify the address rather than simply a protocol

```
udp_socket(io_service, udp::endpoint(boost::asio::ip::address::from_string(""), port))
```

so that you can use `udp_socket.local_endpoint().address()` to get the ip.