# Boost raw sockets

Tags: udp, boost-asio, icmp

I know it is a very theoretical question, but forgive me as this is not my specialty.

Looking for an example on how to use raw sockets with boost, I found a question in this same website where it is assured that you cannot know the destination of an UDP message with boost asio.
Then having a look at the boost examples, there is an icmp example:
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/icmp/ping.cpp
Where you actually can have both IP and ICMP headers by using async_receive and a icmp endpoint.

(I was curious that I couldn't find the word "raw" anywhere in the code)
My question is: why does this work for ICMP and not for UDP or TCP? is it because ICMP is level 3?

How can this example work at all? Is it that ICMP socket is equivalent to a raw socket? but I don't think it should be.

Comment: While Boost.Asio's `udp::socket` does [not expose the ability to identify a received datagram's destination address](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22048365/1053968), one could create a Protocol type that uses raw sockets, allowing the application to process network and transport layer headers.  See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28257640/1053968) for an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`boost::asio::ip::icmp::socket`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ip__icmp/socket.html) is a raw socket.  The [`ip::icmp`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ip__icmp.html) type encapsulates flags and types used for ICMP.  In particular, the [implementation](https://github.com/boostorg/asio/blob/boost-1.58.0/include/boost/asio/ip/icmp.hpp#L63-L67) of [`ip::icmp::type()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ip__icmp/type.html) returns `SOCK_RAW`:

```cpp
/// Obtain an identifier for the type of the protocol.
int type() const
{
  return BOOST_ASIO_OS_DEF(SOCK_RAW);
}
```

As `icmp::socket`'s protocol type is raw, the [ICMP example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples/cpp03_examples.html#boost_asio.examples.cpp03_examples.icmp) will receive the network layer data (IP header and ICMP).   Additionally, the `ip::icmp`'s protocol is `IPPROTO_ICMP`, and Boost.Asio does not set the `IP_HDRINCL` socket option, so the kernel will generate the appropriate IP header when sending.