# Icmp ping with Asio on macOS: Operation not permitted

Tags: c++, macos, icmp, asio

I successfully ported the Asio Pinger example https://think-async.com/Asio/asio-1.20.0/src/examples/cpp03/icmp/ping.cpp to work without Boost at all.

The example works perfectly, but running the app as root on macOS.
As suggested [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/312861/415770) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30900403/boost-raw-sockets), I understand that `asio::ip::icmp` is built on top of raw sockets and macOS doesn't allow raw sockets to non-root users. This force me to run the app as sudo, that's not ideal. Otherwise, it fails with "Operation not permitted".

In the `ping.c` [example](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/312861/415770), they set the socket type as `SOCK_DGRAM` for non-root users. I tried to manually change the flag directly in the `ip\icmp.hpp` [header](https://github.com/chriskohlhoff/asio/blob/08a7029cb10c911b6fb66fb015217a431206e52c/asio/include/asio/ip/icmp.hpp#L65) but of course it does not work: the socket initializes correctly without sudo, but the app crashes sending the packet with `socket_.send_to(request_buffer.data(), destination_);`.

Anyone knows how to run the Pinger example without involving root/sudo?

Thanks