# Socket Connect Ip Addres

Tags: c#, sockets, connect

When i call the function

`Socket.Connect(ip,port)`

If i have active more than one interface, which source ip is chosen?

Is the correct way to set the ip of a client socket with the Bind operation?

Answer (score 0):

The `Socket.LocalEndPoint` property contains the local IP address which is set according to the routing table.

If you wish to decide on the local endpoint yourself you can use the `Bind` method.

```
    aSocket.Bind(theLocalEndpoint);
```

See the [MSDN article here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.bind%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for more information on binding to a custom endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

Windows does not guarantee a specific network interface with `Bind`, it relies upon the routing table to choose which interface is used for the socket, based on the local endpoint specified.

Please see [[Using a specific network interface for a socket in windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2065495/using-a-specific-network-interface-for-a-socket-in-windows]) for a more complete explanation.