# Try to use SO_BINDTODEVICE Socket option in C#

Tags: c#, sockets

Is it possible to use the SO_BINDTODEVICE socket option in c#?

If I need Pivoke, is it also possible in Mono on Linux?

If tryed it, and did not find this option in C#. Is there a way to set it via Pinvoke on a C# Socket?

If someone suggests to use "Bind", this is not possible. Because i want to write a Dhcp server, in need to bind to Ipaddress.any!

Comment: Not a direct duplcate, but you may want to read the related question "[Using a specific network interface for a socket in windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2065495/using-a-specific-network-interface-for-a-socket-in-windows/2080495#2080495)"

Comment: _"Is it possible to use the SO_BINDTODEVICE socket option?"_ -- "is it possible..." questions are best answered by _trying it_. Please provide a good [mcve] showing what you've tried. Explain what that code does, and what you want it to do instead. Please provide a useful, specific question regarding some _specific_ difficulty you have in using this option.