# How to force bind the IP used by TNetHttpClient with 4 LANs present?

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.2-tokyo

I'm using Delphi 10.2 Tokyo. I have 4 internet sources with 4 LANs. I want to make a program using TNetHttpClient. How do I direct it to use a specific internet source?

Comment: You will have to edit your question and clarify your problem.

Comment: Could you add your code with the problem also?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, `TNetHttpClient` does not provide the ability to bind it to a specific LAN. If you need this capability, you will have to find another HTTP library that can do this.

**UPDATE:**

After doing some reading, it turns out that on Windows at least, binding a socket for an *outbound* connection only sets the source IP for the socket's packets, but prior to Vista the actual adapter used for making an IPv4 connection is determined **solely** by Windows' routing tables, the application can't *force* a specific IPv4 adapter to be used.  But for IPv6 traffic, and for IPv4 traffic on Vista+, binding a socket to a specific adapter should work in most cases.

[Q175396: Windows Socket Connection from a Multiple-Homed Computer](https://jeffpar.github.io/kbarchive/kb/175/Q175396/)

[Strong and Weak Host Models](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/technet-magazine/cc137807(v=msdn.10))

[Using a specific network interface for a socket in windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2065495/)

For instance, Indy's `TIdHTTP` has a public `BoundIP` property for binding its socket to a network interface's IP (on platforms that require an interface name instead, you can use the `TIdHTTP.OnSocketAllocated` or `TIdHTTP.OnAfterBind` event to call the `TIdHTTP.Socket.Binding.SetSockOpt()` method, such as for using the `SO_BINDTODEVICE` option on Linux).

Comment: can indy do it? or is there any other way besides ipbind, for example adding a route in windows?

Comment: thanks for your answer. can you give an example of a code snippet?